# Hide number until date is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Column G has an "In Date" and Column H has an "Out Date". Column J has the "Average Days Between" Column G & H. Column K has the "Total Average" of Column J.

In Column K the formula is =AVERAGE(IF(J2:J41<>0,J2:J41,""))

In Column J the formula is =H2-G2

I want the cells in Column J to appear blank until a date is entered into Column H. Currently it shows as -41821 if there is no date in Column H.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H2),"",H2-G2)
```

The null string might break some formulas that are expecting a number though.